# do.call fails for mgcv::gam as string, but not other functions

Tags: r, namespaces, glm, mgcv, do.call

I am trying to fit several different models using a master function as the workhorse (each function calls this master function with the variable `model` as a string and the required parameters passed via `...`)

It works fine for `model = "loess"` and `model = "glm"`, but fails for `model = "gam"`.  Specifically, `do.call(model, args)` will fail unless I hardcode the function name with the namespace.  But I need `model` to be a variable.  The same problem occurs for `formalArgs` which I use to get `args`.  E.g (reprex) based on suggestions from similar SO questions:

```
model <- "mgcv::gam"
formalArgs(mgcv::gam)                   # Works but function is hard-coded
formalArgs(gam)                         # Fails
formalArgs(model)                       # Fails
formalArgs(eval(model))                 # Fails
formalArgs(substitute(model))           # Returns NULL with warning
formalArgs(deparse(substitute(model)))  # Fails
```

The error message is `Error in get(fun, mode = "function", envir = envir) :  object '"mgcv::gam"' of mode 'function' was not found` (or in the case of substitute, returns NULL).

If `model` is changed to `"glm"` or `"loess"`, then `formalArgs(model)` and `formalArgs(eval(model))` work.

I think this has something to do with these two functions both being from the base `stats` package while `gam` is not.  But how do I solve it?

Comment: Regarding base functions vs other packages, `formalArgs("ggplot")` works but `formalArgs("dplyr::select")` does not.  So while not limited to `mgcv::gam`, it is hard to predict which packages it works for and those it doesn't

Comment: `formalArgs` calls `formals(def, envir = parent.frame)`, so the string saved in `model` needs to be present in the environment. So `library(mgcv)` then `model <- "gam"` then `formalArgs(model)` should work.

Comment: `require(mgcv)`  is called in the wrapper function that calls the master function where `formalArgs` and `do.call` reside.  Does it matter where the library is loaded?  Alternatively, is there a way to do something like `formals(def, envir = "mgcv")` so it doesn't matter where?

Comment: I think it should work if it's called before `formalArgs` - e.g. -  `model <- "gam"; fun <- function() {library(mgcv); formalArgs(model)}; fun()`

Comment: @thelatemail Actually, I think for some reason my libraries were reset and `mgcv` hadn't been reloaded while others had.  I think your solution works - `mgcv` just needs to be loaded.  I'll accept this as an answer if you want to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `"mgcv::gam"` is text for an expression, not the name of a function.  The function name is `"gam"`.

To retrieve the formals, you can use `formalArgs(x)` where `x` is the name of a function that's available on the search list, or an actual function object.

That's why `formalArgs(mgcv::gam)` works, because that expression retrieves the function object.  Other ways to do it would be

```r
    model <- mgcv::gam
    formalArgs(model)
#>  [1] "formula"            "family"             "data"              
#>  [4] "weights"            "subset"             "na.action"         
#>  [7] "offset"             "method"             "optimizer"         
#> [10] "control"            "scale"              "select"            
#> [13] "knots"              "sp"                 "min.sp"            
#> [16] "H"                  "gamma"              "fit"               
#> [19] "paraPen"            "G"                  "in.out"            
#> [22] "drop.unused.levels" "drop.intercept"     "nei"               
#> [25] "discrete"           "..."
    model <- "mgcv::gam"
    obj <- eval(parse(text = model))
    formalArgs(obj)
#>  [1] "formula"            "family"             "data"              
#>  [4] "weights"            "subset"             "na.action"         
#>  [7] "offset"             "method"             "optimizer"         
#> [10] "control"            "scale"              "select"            
#> [13] "knots"              "sp"                 "min.sp"            
#> [16] "H"                  "gamma"              "fit"               
#> [19] "paraPen"            "G"                  "in.out"            
#> [22] "drop.unused.levels" "drop.intercept"     "nei"               
#> [25] "discrete"           "..."
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Edited to add:  as the comments to your question said, using `formalArgs("gam")` would also work, but only if `mgcv` was on the search list (because you had run `library(mgcv)` to put it there, or some equivalent).